# Error handling in Python with JSON and a dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, python-2.7

I currently have a Python 2.7 script which scrapes Facebook and captures some JSON data from each page. The JSON data contains personal information. A sample of the JSON data is below:-

```
{
   "id": "4",
   "name": "Mark Zuckerberg",
   "first_name": "Mark",
   "last_name": "Zuckerberg",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/zuck",
   "username": "zuck",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "en_US"
}
```

The JSON values can vary from page to page. The above example lists all the possibles but sometimes, a value such as 'username' may not exist and I may encounter JSON data such as:-

```
{
   "id": "6",
   "name": "Billy Smith",
   "first_name": "Billy",
   "last_name": "Smith",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "en_US"
}
```

With this data, I want to populate a database table. As such, my code is as below:-

```
results_json = simplejson.loads(scraperwiki.scrape(profile_url))
        for result in results_json:
            profile = dict()
            try:
                profile['id'] = int(results_json['id'])
            except:
                profile['id'] = ""
            try:
                profile['name'] = results_json['name']
            except:
                profile['name'] = ""
            try:
                profile['first_name'] = results_json['first_name']
            except:
                profile['first_name'] = ""
            try:
                profile['last_name'] = results_json['last_name']
            except:
                profile['last_name'] = ""
            try:
                profile['link'] = results_json['link']
            except:
                profile['link'] = ""
            try:
                profile['username'] = results_json['username']
            except:
                profile['username'] = ""
            try:
                profile['gender'] = results_json['gender']
            except:
                profile['gender'] = ""
            try:
                profile['locale'] = results_json['locale']
            except:
                profile['locale'] = ""
```

The reason I have so many try/excepts is to account for when the key value doesn't exist on the webpage. Nonetheless, this seems to be a really clumpsy and messy way to handle this issue.

If I remove these try / exception clauses, should my scraper encounter a missing key, it returns a `KeyError` such as `"KeyError: 'username'"` and my script stops running.

Any suggestions on a much smarter and improved way to handle these errors so that, should a missing key be encountered, the script continues.

I've tried creating a list of the JSON values and looked to iterate through them with an IF clause but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`.get()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) instead:

```
>>> a = {'bar': 'eggs'}
>>> a['foo']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'foo'
>>> a.get('foo', 'default value')
'default value'
>>> a.get('bar', 'default value')
'eggs'
```

The `.get()` method returns the value for the requested key, or the default value if the key is missing.

Or you can create a new dict with empty strings for each key and use [`.update()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) on it:

```
profile = dict.fromkeys('id name first_name last_name link username gender locale'.split(), '')
profile.update(result)
```

`dict.fromkeys()` creates a dictionary with all keys you request set to a given default value (`''` in the above example), then we use `.update()` to copy all keys and values from the `result` dictionary, replacing anything already there.

Comment: Sadly, as much as I love the `fromkeys`/`update` solution, I don't think it works in the OP's case. At least one of the values has to be transformed with `int`, and the JSON object may have extra keys that he doesn't want copied into the `profile`. But the `get` answer you also gave obviously doesn't have any such problems, and it's already enough for the OP to make his code 4x more readable and maintainable, which is a pretty huge win.

Comment: @abarnert: the `.fromkeys()`/`.update()` setup works fine, because nothing in the *source* JSON is using `int` either. Don't assume that the `id` is to be treated as an int unless explicitly stated. :-) If there are too many keys it's easy enough to write a generator expression for the update (`.update()` takes tuples as well as a dict).

Comment: In the OP's code, he's got `profile['id'] = int(results_json['id'])`. So, presumably, the JSON has the int rendered a string, but the `profile` has to have an actual integer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters. Perfect - your solution worked as I wishes and it's reduced my cost by 50%. Thanks

Comment: @abarnert: Hrm, not certain how I missed that one. :) Still, a `profile['id'] = int(profile['id'])` isn't that hard to add. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'm guessing you missed it because the OP had 3 lines of repetitive boilerplate for each 1 line of real code—which is exactly what he wanted to fix, and what you helped him fix.